# Receiving broadcast intents with cordova-broadcaster

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the [cordova-broadcaster](https://github.com/bsorrentino/cordova-broadcaster) plugin to receive android broadcast intents. 
I register for the broadcast event

```
   window.broadcaster.addEventListener("com.android.action.SEND_SCAN_RESULT", function (e) { 
         console.log("com.android.action.SEND_SCAN_RESULT received."); 
    });
   console.log("com.android.action.SEND_SCAN_RESULT registered");
```

but if the intent gets fired

```
V/ActivityManager(  775): Broadcast: Intent { act=com.android.action.SEND_SCAN_RESULT flg=0x10 (has extras) } ordered=false userid=0 callerApp=ProcessRecord{1418277c 775:system/1000}
```

the callback does not get triggered.

The only log message is

> com.android.action.SEND_SCAN_RESULT registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the plugin **doesn't manage external broadcast events** but only the local ones

Probably solution could be handle the external event in android and then fire it up to javascript

take a look [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers)

Try this (it should works)

**manifest**

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.action.SEND_SCAN_RESULT" >
                    </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

**Receiver**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcastSync(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: The broadcast received but the extra informations are empty, Do we need to do anything ?

Comment: Check if you have put the information in “userdata” field and such info are in correct json format

Answer (score 1):

Try instead [cordova-plugin-intent](https://github.com/darryncampbell/darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent). Look for `intentShim.registerBroadcastReceiver`.